# How to count the number of times a specific text string appears and group it by other columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have a table `population_table` that contains columns with a `user_id`, `provider_name`, and `city`. I want to count the number of times a user appears in each city, per provider. So for instance, I would want the output to look something like this:

```
provider_name |  Users |  Atlanta | Chicago | New York
______________________________________________________
Alpha            100        50         25        25
Beta             200       100         75        25
Kappa            500       300        100       100
```

I tried using:

```
select provider_name, count (distinct user_id) AS Users, count(city) AS City 
from population_table
group by provider_name
```

How can I write this query to get the breakdown of the users per provider per city?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation.  It is not clear from your description that `count(distinct)` is necessary.  So I would try this first:

```
select provider_name, count(*) AS Users,
       sum(case when city = 'Atlanta' then 1 else 0 end) as Atlanta,
       sum(case when city = 'Chicago' then 1 else 0 end) as Chicago,
       sum(case when city = 'New York' then 1 else 0 end) as New_York
from population_table
group by provider_name;
```

If `count(distinct)` is necessary:

```
select provider_name, count(distinct user_id) AS Users,
       count(distinct case when city = 'Atlanta' then user_id end) as Atlanta,
       count(distinct case when city = 'Chicago' then user_id end) as Chicago,
       count(distinct case when city = 'New York' then user_id end) as New_York
from population_table
group by provider_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable number of cities, I do not know how to supply the list in SparkSQL.  But using pyspark, you could create output `table` from `input` like this:

```
counts = input.groupBy('provider_name', 'city').count().cache()
countsPerProvider = counts.groupBy('provider_name').count().withColumnRenamed("count", "users")
pivoted = counts.groupBy("provider_name").pivot("city").sum('count')
table = pivoted.join(countsPerProvider, pivoted["provider_name"] == countsPerProvider["provider_name"]).select(pivoted["*"], countsPerProvider["users"])
```